# Skipping document lines according to count

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, filereader

I have three Objects, and a constructor, but i cant figure out how to read in the correct data.

I have an idea, create a count, and then skip lines according to the count. but i have no idea how to put it in code. I have 3 sets of data for 3 different objects. Here is the constructor i'm using.

```
public StudentRec() throws FileNotFoundException {

    {

        firstname = scan.next();
        lastname = scan.next();
        age = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println(firstname + " " + lastname + " " + age);
    }

}
```

Here are the objects.

```
    StudentRec Student1 = new StudentRec();
    StudentRec Student2 = new StudentRec();
    StudentRec Student3 = new StudentRec();
```

Of course all it does is read the first line of data and put it in every object. How would I read the first line of the data, then when it's time for the next student, Skip the first line and read in the next line.

The data as you can see is just

Firstname Lastname Age

FirstName Lastname Age

As it appears in the document.

Comment: Where does the input come from?

Comment: From a file name Studentinfo.txt I have other code in the class i just cut it off.

Comment: First row "firstname", second row "lastname", third row "age", fourth row "firstname" and so on?

Comment: Bob Bobbers 19 (new line)
John Johners 20 (new line)
Kat Katters 21

Comment: And you are able to fill ony student rec, but the second one gets the same values passed as the first one, because file-reading begins at the start again?

Comment: Yup! thats pretty much the problem haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the file reading out of the student recs so that you read the three triplets one after another and create three separate objects in a row.

Comment: Well the instructions specifcally asked for a constructor.

Comment: Then store a counter and do a for-loop in the constructor, with the three value read ins as one for-iteration.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem.. I'm not so sure how to set it up that way. Would the counter be in the constructor?

Comment: Yip, I would place it there. And either pass it in or make it static for the class.

Comment: Alright i got the count to the right area but now to implement it is the problem. I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Use a bufferedReader to read each line in the txt file.

```
  BufferedReader in
       = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("student.txt"));

    String[] studentData = in.readLine().split(" ");
```

It will read each line from your text file, and split the data based on spaces.